# How to get the coordinates of the maximum in xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Simple question: I don't only want the value of the maximum but also the coordinates of it in an xarray DataArray. How to do that?

I can, of course, write my own simple reduce function, but I wonder if there is anything built-in in xarray?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Update:

xarray now has the `idxmax` method for selecting the coords of the max values along one dimension:

```py
In [8]: da = xr.DataArray(
   ...:     np.random.rand(2,3),
   ...:     dims=list('ab'),
   ...:     coords=dict(a=list('xy'), b=list('ijk'))
   ...: )


In [14]: da
Out[14]:
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2, b: 3)>
array([[0.63059257, 0.00155463, 0.60763418],
       [0.19680788, 0.43953352, 0.05602777]])
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) <U1 'x' 'y'
  * b        (b) <U1 'i' 'j' 'k'

In [13]: da.idxmax('a')
Out[13]:
<xarray.DataArray 'a' (b: 3)>
array(['x', 'y', 'x'], dtype=object)
Coordinates:
  * b        (b) <U1 'i' 'j' 'k'
```

The below answer is still relevant for the maximum over multiple dimensions, though.

---

You can use [`da.where()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) to filter based on the max value:

```
In [17]: da = xr.DataArray(
             np.random.rand(2,3), 
             dims=list('ab'), 
             coords=dict(a=list('xy'), b=list('ijk'))
         )

In [18]: da.where(da==da.max(), drop=True).squeeze()
Out[18]:
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(0.96213673)
Coordinates:
    a        <U1 'x'
    b        <U1 'j'
```

Edit: updated the example to show the indexes more clearly, now that xarray doesn't have default indexes

Comment: Very nice. Could add `.squeeze()` to squeeze out scalar dimensions.

Comment: Just a note that if your field/dataarray naturally contains NaN values, then when you `drop=True`, those values are discarded. This could leave tothe wrong x/y coordinates

Answer (score 7):

An `idxmax()` method would be [very welcome](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/60) in xarray, but nobody has gotten around to implementing it yet.

For now, you can find the coordinates of the maximum by combining `argmax` and `isel`:

```
>>> array = xarray.DataArray(
...    [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]],
...    dims=['x', 'y'],
...    coords={'x': [1, 2], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

>>> array
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3)>
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c'

>>> array.isel(y=array.argmax('y'))
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2)>
array([3, 3])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
    y        (x) <U1 'c' 'a'
```

This is probably what `.max()` should do in every case! Unfortunately we're not quite there yet.

The problem is that it doesn't yet generalize to the maximum over multiple dimensions in the way we would like:

```
>>> array.argmax()  # what??
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(2)
```

The problem is that it's automatically flattening, like `np.argmax`. Instead, we probably want something like an array of tuples or a tuple of arrays, indicating the original integer coordinates for the maximum. Contributions for this would also be welcome -- see [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1388) for more details.

Comment: `idxmax()` recently got merged! https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/3871

Answer (score 2):

You can also use stack :

Let's say data is a 3d variable with time, longitude, latitude and you want the coordinate of the maximum through time.

```
stackdata = data.stack(z=('lon', 'lat'))
maxi = stackdata.argmax(axis=1)
maxipos = stackdata['z'][maxi]
lonmax = [maxipos.values[itr][0] for itr in range(ntime)]
latmax = [maxipos.values[itr][1] for itr in range(ntime)]
```

Comment: what is stackpr?

Answer (score 1):

This will return the coordinate points of the max value in a xarray dataarray.

```
max = xarraydata.where(xarraydata==xarraydata.max(), drop=True).squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the coordinates of the single maximum value in an xarray `da` then I don't think the accepted answer is correct. Furthermore, if there is naturally a `NaN` value in the array, the answers above the `drop=True` will remove those `NaN` values and give incorrect coordinates. This code worked well for me:

```
where = np.where(da==da.max())
```

Which will give, for example,

```
(array([0]), array([25]), array([598]), array([25]))
```

Showing the maximum value is at `0,25,598,25`. And it could also be accessed with `da[where]`.