# Finding coordinates corresponding to maximum across 2 dimensions in a 3d array

Tags: python-xarray

This is closely related to an earlier [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179593/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-maximum-in-xarray) but I am having some trouble reproducing the solution there with a 3d array. My 3d array has one time coordinate and two spatial coordinates. Each spatial coordinate is itself a two-dimensional function of the indices along the spatial dimensions, as might be the case with (longitude,latitude) values when the spatial grid is curvilinear.

**Goal:** For each time, I want to find the coordinates corresponding to the maximum in space. Here is some code:

```
# Create cftime object to mimic my real data.
yr1=250; yr2=250
times = xr.cftime_range(start=format(yr1,'04d') + '-01',
                                        end  =format(yr2,'04d') + '-02',
                                        freq='1MS',calendar='noleap')

x=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3); y = x;

nt=len(times); ny=x.shape[0]; nx=x.shape[1]

# Create the dataarray object
dummy = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.random([nt,ny,nx]),dims=['t','iy','ix'], 
                     coords=dict( time=(['t'],times), x=(['iy','ix'],x), y=(['iy','ix'],y) ) )

dummy.where(dummy==dummy.max(dim=['ix','iy']),drop=True ).squeeze()
```

See the pasted image below to see the output from the last command. It does not look like the coordinates with `nan` values are being dropped. At each time, the array has size 2 x 2, when it should be 2 x 3 with the max. value and 5 `nan` values. Finally, if the `drop` command were working, I should be seeing only two scalar numbers in the output of cell 78.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, I can't figure out what to expect from `.where` when coordinates are functions of the indices. Have you thought of using `.stack` as a workaround? If I understand it correctly stacking the array on 'ix' and 'ix' and taking `.idxmax()` should give you the iy and ix indices you are looking for.

```
    dummy_stacked=dummy.stack(z=['ix','iy'])
    dummy_stacked.idxmax('z')
```